# huggingface pipeline: bert NER task throws RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (921) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-tokenizers

I try to set up a german ner, pretrained with bert via the huggingface pipeline. For some texts the following code throws an error "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (921) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1" for the line "ner = classifier(text)".

I already did some research with stackoverflow and this is the most similar problem i found:[The size of tensor a (707) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320883/the-size-of-tensor-a-707-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-512-at-non-singleto)

The solution sounds good, I just don't know where i can specify those settings while using the huggingface pipeline. What do I need to change in my code to make it work properly?

thanks!

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('ner', model="fhswf/bert_de_ner", grouped_entities=True)
text = (dic[pi].text)
ner = classifier(text)
```

Comment: The solution in the link you have posted is truncation. WHat you actually want to do for NER is a [sliding window approach](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/66#issuecomment-436378461). AFAIK this requires some coding from your side. I would use a [fasttokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.5.1/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerFast) and use `stride` with `return_overflowing_tokens` to preprocess `text` object.