# RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (585) must match the existing size (514) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I want to predict the sentiment of thousands of sentences using huggingface.

```
from transformers import pipeline
model_path = "cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment"
pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model_path, tokenizer=model_path)

from datasets import load_dataset

data_files = {
    "train": "/content/data_customer.csv"
}

dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files=data_files)

dataset = dataset.map(lambda examples: dict(pipe(examples['text'])))
```

but I am getting the following error.

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (585) must match the existing size (514) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [1, 585].  Tensor sizes: [1, 514]
```

This post suggests a way to fix the issue but doesn't say how to fix it in pipeline.
[The size of tensor a (707) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320883/the-size-of-tensor-a-707-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-512-at-non-singleto)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply add tokenizer arguments when you init the pipeline.

```
pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model_path, tokenizer=model_path, max_length=512, truncation=True)
```